# Add space in String

Tags: php

I would like to add space during string assignment like:

```
$movie_genre.= $row["movie_genre"]."   ";
```

where it should display genre1 genre2 genre3 and so on. Single space between these three genres is required. Currently it is showing genre1genre2genre3

Comment: what about using a trim() ??

Comment: What is the problem exactly? the example you have given should work.

Comment: Try first `var_dump($array)` to the array to check each item the use `implode(" ", $array);` just as an option... but your example should also work

Comment: please post more code..

Comment: Why my code is not working perfectly?

Comment: I just need to expand string with space in words just like we write sentence where each word is writing with leading space that make it readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collect it in an array & then use `implode`:

```
{// your loop starts
  $movie_genre[] = $row["movie_genre"];
}//// your loop ends

echo implode(" ", $movie_genre);
```

Comment: you are making it complicated.

Comment: @sgt: I don't think so … it's a pretty straightforward approach to get a the items delimited correctly, while avoiding a delimiter at the end.

Comment: i think there is no need to use `implode` when it can be generated inside the loop..

Comment: @sgt: But you'll end up with an extra space in the end, which might not seem like a huge problem, but it might not be intended behavior. Also, internally, `implode()` does basically the same as a loop, but without the ending delimiter, neatly tucked away in a single function.

Answer (score 0):

@MuhammadMuazzam,Please check below code.

```
//Suppose your data array like below.(Below is sample example)
$dataArray = array('data1','data2','data3'); 
$numItems = count($dataArray);
$i = 0;

$movie_genre = '';
foreach($dataArray as $value)
{
    if(++$i === $numItems) {
       $movie_genre.= $value;
    } else {
        $movie_genre.= $value." ";
    }
}
echo $movie_genre;
```

Comment: With this solution you'll end up with an extra space on the end. This might not be intended behavior in the application, so use of `implode()` might be better.

Comment: @Rik_S,Edited My answer,Check it now.Yes Implode is also working fine but this is alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your existing code is perfect,

just add a single line [rtim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

```
$movie_genre.= $row["movie_genre"] . " ";
$movie_genre = rtrim($movie_genre);
```